Local convergence and convergence in norm
I have difficulties with this problem: Given $f_1, f_2, \dots$ such that $f_n \to f^*$ in $L^p_{loc}\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)$ and $\left\|f_n\right\|_{L^p\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)} \to a \in \mathbb{R}^+$ increasingly. Can we have that $\left\|f^*\right\|_{L^p\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)} = a$?
I'm trying with this approach: Choosing $m \to \infty$ and
$$a = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d}\left|f_n\right|^p = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \lim\limits_{m\to \infty}\int\limits_{B\left(0,m\right)}\left|f_n\right|^p.$$
Here, I want to exchange the order of two limits but it seems there is no result for this case.
Thank you very much for your help.

This is false. Easy counter-example: $d=1,p=1, f_n=1_{(n,n+1)},a=1,f^{*}=0$. On any bounded set $f_n\equiv 0$ for $n$ sufficiently large, so $f_n \to f^{*}$ locally in $L^{p}$. However, $\|f^{*}\|_{L^{p}}=0\neq a$.

This is a clear counter-example. Why is there a vote for deletion?

Thank you very much for your clear example and your help. I don't know who voted for deletion. I've just backed here and sorry for this late reply.
